# SharePoint SSE getPreviews errors for search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We migrated from SharePoint 2019 to SSE and noticed that the search result page (search.aspx) looks different and includes "previews" of the files. However, this has caused an issue.

When the users search for shared documents, it will call to https://mytenant:444/sites/mySite/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?clientType=docLibGrid&guidFile={37B1BEE0-BEDF-44F9-B139-18786FE5763F}&guidSite=8ba531af-1e7c-4139-b252-dfdd3ffb92ad&guidWeb=a7b15707-fc90-46ab-8b4a-5478cee018e4

And this will prompt the user to log in again/SSO not working, which we do not want. What could the reason be?

The previews is not needed in a business perspective, can these be removed? We also thought about copy/paste the old search.aspx to the new solution as a temporary solution (guess that a patch will break this).